# Color trouble with Rmarkdown generated HTML tables

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, tablehtml

Maybe this is just a stupid browser related issue, but ...

I generate some colored tables in a HTML file via `Rmarkdown` using the `tableHTML` package (colors are generated by the `RColorBrewer` package):

````
```{r Init, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
require(magrittr, quietly = TRUE)
require(tableHTML)
test <- data.frame(A=123, B=456, C=789)
```
````

...

````
```{r Test, echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
tableHTML(test) %>%
  add_css_thead(css = list('background-color', '#4DAF4A')) %>%
  add_css_table(css = list('border', '#4DAF4A'))
```
````

The colors of the borders look fine in the `Rstudio' viewer:

[image: RStudio viewer]

But the borders are colored different, when opening in Safari or Firefox:

[image: Safari] [image: Firefox]

What is the problem with table border colors?

Comment: Hm - just recognized that it works with Chrome. I hate browsers. Sometimes. Anyway - would be great to understand that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you very much for your question!

With `add_css_table`, the style is applied to the `table`-tag and with `add_css-thead`, it is applied to the `thead` tag. But I think to get the effect you are looking for, you can apply the styles to the `th` and `td` tags via the functions `add_css_header` and `add_css_column`:

```r
tableHTML(test) %>%
    add_css_header(css = list(c("background-color", "border"),
                              c("#4DAF4A", "1px solid #4DAF4A")),
                   headers = 0:4) %>% 
    add_css_column(css = list("border", "1px solid #4DAF4A"),
                   columns = c("rownames", names(test)))
```

In RStudio, it looks like this:

[image: table_rstudio]

In Firefox:

[image: table_firefox]

And in Chrome:

[image: table_chrome]

Comment: Thanks a lot @clemens. That's it!

Comment: I am glad I could help! Feel free to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.colorhexa.com/4daf4a the closest websafe colour to "#4daf4a" is "#669933". Does changing the border to #669933 solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the border colors remain different. But good to know about that link, featuring websafe colors.

Comment: Sorry - I was fairly sure that would solve the problem - I'll look into it further